# EF ChangeTracker entity collections count always 0

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In order to execute some actions for all entities deletions I'm trying to handle it like this:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var deletedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
        .Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Deleted).ToList();

    foreach (var deletedEntity in deletedEntities)
    {
        //((SampleEntity)deletedEntity.Entity).SuperCollection.Count();
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

I need to handle some entity collections during the deletion process based on the entity collection properties count, but it always returns 0, even when the collection has many items.

```
((SampleEntity)deletedEntity.Entity).SuperCollection.Count();
```

**Any idea why my collections are always 0 at this point?**

My models are properly lazy loading coded as following and my collections works very well out of the SaveChanges()

```
public partial class SampleEntity
{
    public int MyId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public SampleEntity()
    {
        this.SuperCollection = new HashSet<UnitCompany>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<AnyOtherEntity> SuperCollection { get; set; }
}
```

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call DetectChanges before:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
    //...
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Otherwise, changes will be detected only in `base.SaveChanges()` method.

EF will drop all references to related objects for deleted entites. If you need to save this relations, you can save them in local field:

```
class UnitCompany
{
    private SampleEntity _entity;
    private SampleEntity _prevEntity;

    publc SampleEntity Entity
    {
        get { return _entity; }
        set 
        { 
            if (value != null)
            {
                _prevEntity = value;
            }
            _entity = value;
        }
    }
}
```

`_prevEntity` keeps link to related object and you can get it in `SaveChanges`

Comment: Calling DetectChanges() I got the same issue. Indeed, ChangeTracker is tracking the changes as expected. Debugging my code I noticed my entity is losing all collections properties relations count right after the execution of `db.SampleEntity.Remove(db.SampleEntity.Find(1234)` even before entering in `public override int SaveChanges() { }`. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @RubensMussiCury this is how EF works. After removing entity it will drop all relations with child/parent entities

Comment: would you please have any suggestion in order to keep these relations when I set to delete/remove my entity?

Comment: @RubensMussiCury you can save property value to some field before delete operation, and then extract it: https://gist.github.com/Backs/47284b79c724d182d8c560c76ec49df5

Comment: sounds a good approach... how do you consider about creating a basic EF repository for this purpose? Also, would you please edit your answer or just answer again my question to get an answered mark...

Comment: @RubensMussiCury added example to answer