# EF ChangeTracker SoftDelete

Tags: c#, entity-framework, soft-delete

I'm looking for a better way for implementing the following logic (HasAnyRelation and SetDeleteMarks) into ChangeTracker in order to avoid rewriting this logic for all my entities.

The problem is that once we call Remove() it will drop all relations with child/parent entities and I can't check the relations into ChangeTracker anymore.

[In this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45067138/ef-changetracker-entity-collections-count-always-0) I got a suggestion to implement a copy of my previous entity to keep my collections intact after Remove(). However it works, I also would have to implement the logic many times.

Does anybody would have any other approach to achieve it?

Regards

**CONTROLLER DELETE ACTION**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Delete(Sector sector)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var currentEntity = db.Sector.Find(sector.SectorId);
        var hasAnyRelation = EntityHelper.HasAnyRelation(currentEntity);
        if (hasAnyRelation)
        {
            currentEntity = (Sector)EntityHelper.SetDeleteMarks(currentEntity);
            db.Sector.Attach(currentEntity);
            db.Entry(currentEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        else
        {
            db.Sector.Attach(currentEntity);
            db.Sector.Remove(currentEntity);
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**ENTITY HELPER**

```
public static class EntityHelper
{
public static object SetDeleteMarks(object entityObj)
{
    var deletedProperty = entityObj.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name == "Deleted").FirstOrDefault();
    var nameProperties = entityObj.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name.Contains("Name"));

    if (deletedProperty != null)
    {
        deletedProperty.SetValue(entityObj, true);
        foreach (var nameProperty in nameProperties)
        {
            var deletedMark = "(*)";
            var currentValue = nameProperty.GetValue(entityObj).ToStringNullSafe();
            if (!currentValue.Contains(deletedMark) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentValue))
            {
                nameProperty.SetValue(entityObj, String.Format("{0} {1}", currentValue, deletedMark).Trim());
            }
        }
    }

    return entityObj;
}

public static bool HasAnyRelation(object entityObj)
{
    var collectionProps = GetManyRelatedEntityNavigatorProperties(entityObj);

    foreach (var item in collectionProps)
    {
        var collectionValue = GetEntityFieldValue(entityObj, item.Name);
        if (collectionValue != null && collectionValue is IEnumerable)
        {
            var col = collectionValue as IEnumerable;
            if (col.GetEnumerator().MoveNext())
            {
                return true;
            }

        }
    }

    return false;
}

private static object GetEntityFieldValue(this object entityObj, string propertyName)
{
    var pro = entityObj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).First(x => x.Name == propertyName);
    return pro.GetValue(entityObj, null);

}

private static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetManyRelatedEntityNavigatorProperties(object entityObj)
{
    var props = entityObj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(x => x.CanWrite && x.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual && x.PropertyType.IsGenericType == true);
    return props;
}
}
```